# ParametricPlot 2D with 2 parameters

Tags: plotting, functions, parameters

```
f1[r_, t_] := r^0.8 { Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sin[t]};
f2[t_] := {t, Sin[t]};
f3[t_] := 1.5 {t, Cos[t]};

ParametricPlot[{f1[r, t], f2[t], f3[t]}, {t, -2, 2}, {r, 0, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.1, Blue]], {Blue, Thick}, {Red, 
    Thick}}]
```

This is my sample code. I would like to use PlotStyle with custom colors for f2[t] and f3[t]. However, Mathematica automatically chooses the colors.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f1[r_, t_] := r^(4/5) {Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sin[t]};
f2[t_] := {t, Sin[t]};
f3[t_] := 3/2 {t, Cos[t]};

Show[
 ParametricPlot[f1[r, t],
  {t, -2, 2}, {r, 0, 3},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Blue],
  PlotLegends -> {f1}],
 ParametricPlot[{f2[t], f3[t]},
  {t, -2, 2},
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}},
  PlotLegends -> {f2, f3}],
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-1, 2.5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thank you !!!!